# Overwritten model not called

Tags: magento-1.8, overrides

I have created a class `Customcode_Sales_Model_Order` that I want to rewrite a function in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` with.

I have set up my config.xml in Customcode/Sales/etc as follows:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <model>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order>Customcode_Sales_Model_Order</order>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </model>
    </global>
</config>
```

and declared my class in Customcode/Sales/Model like this:

```
<?php 

class Customcode_Sales_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order
{
    public function getShippingMethod()
    {
        /** my code here */
    }
}
```

I've also made sure to create Customcode_Sales.xml in etc/modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Customcode_Sales>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Customcode_Sales>
    </modules>
</config>
```

However, when I debug the original function still gets hit. Is there anything I might have missed or misspelled?

Comment: have you checked the class using factory methods like Mage::getModel('sales/order'); and echo get_class to see which class is intantiated

Comment: I have not, I will try quickly - what result should I be getting?

Comment: you should get your class name if all things went fine

Comment: Thanks, I did it and got Mage_Sales_Model_Order, telling me that there is a problem somewhere. I will continue to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config code as below:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order>Customcode_Sales_Model_Order</order>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

It is `models` not `model`

Also make sure if any other extension override the same core class then you need to rewrite extended class.

Comment: You nailed it. Thank you very much, I don't like copy pasting code, I tend to type it all out, which is what caused this issue.